# background-image for wrapper div is not working

Tags: html, css, wrapper

I have to design a site with a frameset.

I want to make one frame with the main page and another with a menu on the right. But framesets are ugly most times, aren't they? So I want to define a background image for a wrapper div and a little border on the left in `#4e4e4e` to make it a bit nicer. But this doesn't work. I don't see any image even though it seems to be embedded correctly.

And can you tell me how to do that thing with left grey border? I thought of a left border for the wrapper but I am not sure.

Thanks!

```
<style>
#wrapper {
    background-image: url(../img/rook/img/fever.jpg);
    background-color: #4e4e4e;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id=wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li>Main</li>
            <li>History</li>
        </ul>
        <br>
        <!--...-->
    </div>
```

Comment: Please post questions in short.
Explain the main parts only.

Comment: Are you sure that image is loaded ? Have you given the proper path to image ?

Comment: Please don't use frames to separate content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id = "wrapper">
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're lacking a quotation mark around the ID "wrapper"

it should look like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
  ...
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id=wrapper">
```

just correct this line to

```
<div id="wrapper">
```